# ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Application Logs out automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC 5 web application project, and I just uploaded it to a server. 
Now the problem is when I try to open the page to create some new record, it automatically navigates me to the login page.

I am using standard ActionResult. Index, Create, Update.. and so on.
How do I stop this?

Here is the code:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {

             return View();
        }
```

Although I am logged in as an Admin, but when I try to open it, it still navigates me to login page.

Comment: you must have enabled some kind of authentication. check the config file.

Comment: Check if you have the `[Authorize]` attribute on your controller or any of its actions, if so remove it if you don't want to be logged in to view that action

Comment: @Rundresha, how do I check that?

Comment: @zgood, yes I have used that. And when I logged in, try to call the Create action it again navigates me to login page.

Comment: you want to access your actions anonymously? or with user logged in?

Comment: with users logged in

Comment: Can you provide the code? We can't predict using this.

Comment: I just added the code, please have a look.